# Custom logout redirection in laravel for admin guard

Tags: php, laravel

How to make a custom Logout for the admin guard where admin log out redirect to the admin login page and not user login page?

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->invalidate();
    return redirect()->route('admin.login');  //redirects to user home page and not admin login page
}
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard('admin');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try following code :

```
    /**
 * Log the user out of the application.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function logout(Request $request)
{

    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect()->guest(route( 'admin.login' ));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i use package laravel/ui and mcamara (localization), my solutions is:

```
// login controller:

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    public function __construct()
        {
            $this->redirectTo = '/'.app()->getLocale();
            $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        }
}


// in file 
// vendor/laravel/ui/auth-backend/AuthenticatesUsers.php
// in method logout

// from
return $request->wantsJson()
  ? new Response('', 204)
  : redirect('/');
// to
return $request->wantsJson()
  ? new Response('', 204)
  : redirect($this->redirectTo);
```